# Why am I getting "Command 'deb' not found"?

Tags: repository, deb

I have come across several installation instructions that include the command `deb`. But it appears that this command is not available on my installation.

Where can I get this command? Is there a work-around?

Comment: Please accept an answer to questions where you have a good answer, to show that you like an answer and it helped you the most. You can do so with the checkmark to the left.

Comment: I'm embarassed that I didn't realize the instructions I was reading weren't showing me something to type at the command line, it was showing me a line to put in a file. I'm glad you asked this question!

Answer (score 154):

`deb` is not a command. It is used in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file to indicate a Debian software repository.

From [Ubuntu Manpage - sources.list](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man5/sources.list.5.html):

> The source list is designed to support any number of active sources
> and a variety of source media. The file lists one source per line,
> with the most preferred source listed first. The format of each line
> is: type uri args. The first item, type determines the format for
> args.  uri is a Universal Resource Identifier (URI), which is a
> superset of the more specific and well-known Universal Resource
> Locator, or URL.
>
> The deb type describes a typical two-level Debian archive,
> distribution/component. The format for a sources.list entry using the
> deb and deb-src types is:
>
> ```
> deb [ options ] uri distribution [component1] [component2] [...]
> ```
>
> The URI for the deb type must specify the base of the Debian
> distribution, from which APT will find the information it needs.
> distribution can specify an exact path, in which case the components
> must be omitted and distribution must end with a slash (/). This is
> useful for when the case only a particular sub-section of the archive
> denoted by the URI is of interest. If distribution does not specify an
> exact path, at least one component must be present.

So, if I have `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ quantal main restricted` in the `sources.list` file - it says: I have a Debian archive which is based on `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/`, the *distribution* is `quantal` and the *components* are `main` and `restricted`.

Comment: And `sources.list` is in `/etc/apt/` on 12.04.

Comment: Can be useful if you say that "deb" lines are instructions added to Aptitude source lists. That would eliminate the amount of confusion this whole issue creates.

Comment: I hit the same problem because of confusing guidance on the [pgAdmin installation page](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt).

Comment: In my case a copy/paste issue converted double-quotes (") into a similar but different character which caused the command to give following error. Notice the funny quote character before deb.
'“deb' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudfoundry-cli.list

Answer (score 35):

`deb` is not a unix command. If you have a line like the following (source for docker):

```
deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial main
```

it is a line that must be available in your ubuntu `sources.list` so that `apt-get` can find future packages from this new source.

However, it's not a good practice to edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file directly. Instead add the `deb` line as an entry to a new `.list` file inside the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory. We will create a `docker.list` file like this:

```
echo "deb https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
```

Once done, remember to perform a `sudo apt-get update` and you should now be able to find new packages from this source easily.

Answer (score 28):

Like the answer by [@Eric Carvalho](https://askubuntu.com/users/65926/eric-carvalho) `deb` is not command line If you have deb then url like this:

```
deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian trusty contrib
```

**Edit**

Like commit of [@muru](https://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru), you need to create new file with the extension `.list` into `/etc/apt/source.list.d/` folder:

**Example**:
I want to download Oracle virtualbox, create new file :

```
sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/oracle-virtualbox-trusty.list
```

Then copy and paste the line of deb into this file

Comment: 1. It's `apt`, not `opt` (though there is an `opt`) and 2. Never edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to add a line unless it is an Ubuntu mirror/official repository. Create a new file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` with the extension `.list` with that line.

Comment: @muru "*Never edit /etc/apt/sources.list to add a line unless it is an Ubuntu mirror/official repository.*" Why? Sure, making `.list` files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` is what *I* do under these circumstances and is what I usually recommend. But I see no reason to *insist* manually added 3rd party software sources go in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. Some conffiles are when possible best not edited by the user (e.g., use `/etc/profile.d` over `/etc/profile`, arguably use `/etc/sudoers.d` over `/etc/sudoers`), but `sources.list` is often changed. (Even customized by Ubiquity to a regional mirror.)

Comment: @EliahKagan when have you ever seen Ubiquity add a third-party repository (not mirror) to sources.list? Or for that matter, any official tool? sources.list.d is present for a reason. I will continue to insist that it be used for third-party repositories.

Comment: @muru Sorry, I wasn't clear. I mentioned Ubiquity's behavior to point out `/etc/apt/sources.list` isn't one of the [conffiles that one can leave alone so as to facilitate smoother upgrading](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ap-pkg-conffiles.html)--as that is often (perhaps usually) the motivation behind *strong* suggestions to prefer making files in `X.d` to editing `X`. I am not suggesting Ubiquity enables third-party repos in any way. You haven't explained what's special about such repos, though, so as to make it actually *wrong* (i.e., "Never edit...") to put them in `sources.list`.

Comment: @EliahKagan There's nothing "actually wrong" in doing so, if that's your problem with the statement. "Never [do X]" doesn't always mean that doing X is wrong, it can and does mean that doing X is bad practice ("Never use GOTO."). Happy, now? Repeat: I will continue to insist that sources.list.d be used for third party repositories and sources.list only for mirrors and official repos, unless you can give me a clear, sound, reason as to why it is a good idea not to do so.

Comment: @muru you are correct, I edit my answer

Answer (score 17):

On Ubuntu, you don't have to manually edit the `source.list` to add the repository.
Instead, you can use `add-apt-repository`, as you would do for a PPA.

For example, to add the LLVM repository, you can call:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://apt.llvm.org/trusty/ llvm-toolchain-trusty main'
```

As you can see, we must pass the `deb` line as a single argument to the command.

Answer (score 11):

Deb isn't actually a command (I thought so too, at first) --  **Assuming you are trying to download/install a deb, do this (for example):**

`wget http://whatever.com/whatever.deb`

then `dpkg -i whatever.deb`

then run the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: 100% relevant, and better than the best answer above. He's obviously trying to download/install a .deb

Answer (score 4):

This is **not the CLI command.**

This is information about some Debian package repository (used also by Ubuntu).

If you want to use this repository:

1. Open the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` with administrator privileges.
2. Add to this file a line with information about the repository starting with `deb ...`
3. Save the file.
4. Run this command:

   apt-get update

Now you will be able to use this repository.

Answer (score 0):

Add following line before apt update\installs in your dockerfile:

RUN echo 'deb [check-valid-until=no] http://archive.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main' > /etc/apt/sources.list